# Problems with USB port and Littlefuse ESD protection on ESP32 and Mac

Tags: usb, esp32, esd

I needs some help for select/wiring USB 2.0 port, which is for ESD protection.

should mention that I'm not that much experience with ESD before, so google it and finally choose littlefuse lineup.

As mentioned on ESD suppression design guide for USB 2.0 documentation (as followed figure), I print PCB and soldered but USB port is not detected on computer (Mac).

[image]

Micro controller is ESP32 with silicon lab CP2014. (As it’s data sheet, it support 'USB Specification 2.0 compliant; full-speed (12 Mbps)’)

It’s bit different from figure below. I selected 1206L700SLPR, instead of 1205L075. But others parts (SP1003, SP3014) are same as guide document. (But I don’t think it’s not a big problem).

Here are the actual schematic/board layout.

[image]
[image]

I double checked solar parts SP3014 because it’s so small SMD. As soon as remove SP3014, port was detected. So I guess related with that one. Can you help me ? Did I miss something or design wrong ?

double check sorder condition on SP3014.
compare with/without SP3014 for USB port detected.

Comment: Why do you have the SP3014 connected to some weird case ground instead of the USB ground? Are they connected in any way? Where? Also, the USB differential data pair is not routed as a differetial pair, and likely not with correct differential or single ended impedance either. It just looks like two random unrelated wires. Why?

Comment: @Justme thank you for comment. I just followed guideline figure. in document, `chasis ground` is not `USB signal ground`. so SP3014 `GND` connected to `chasis ground`. USB port gnd and usb2.0 controller gnd are connected as `signal ground`. am I wrong ?

Comment: also I don't understand exactly what `USB differential data pair is not routed as a differential pair` means. right side of schematic `USB 4 wire` act like usb port connector of microcontroller which will go to CP2012 bridge. the molex 4 connector, where left of schematic will act like usb cable. if connection is wrong then it doesn't work without SP3014.

Comment: OK.. I just jump them with jumper wire between E_GND (CHASIS ground) and I_GND(signal ground). then port was detected.  I have another question. so there is no problem in case of External GND and Internal GND(signal GND) are shorted? I know this is so stupid question..

Comment: Look, we have no clue what your device is and how it has the different grounds connected and where. But it won't work unless they are correct. We don't have enough info to say what's correct or incorrect about the connections. But if you are not sure how things should be connected, it is very bold to just connect to your expensive Mac and hope it does not burn up.

Comment: @Justme thank you for your comment. there are two VCC. VCC1 support 5V, which will use for sensors and ESP32. other VCC2 is from USB port and this port is only use for upload/debugging purpose on ESP32. the picture/schematic what i upload here is the interface board for ESD protection. everything is working without ESD protection circuit.